# friend function in derived class with private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

If a class Derived is inherited privately from a class Base and the Derived class has a friend function f(), so what members can f() access from Derived class and Base class.

```
class Base {
public:
    int a;
protected:
    int b;
private:
    int c;
};  


class Derived: private Base {    
    void friend f() {}

public:
    int d;
protected:
    int e;
private:
    int f;
};
```

I understand that if a class is inherited privately from the base class, everything is private in the derived class.

But why in the code above, the function f() can access a, b, d, e, f but not c?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'Friendship' grants access to the class that declares the friend - it's not transitive. To use a bad analogy - my friends are not necessarily my dad's friends.

The C++ FAQ has a bit more detail:

- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.4

Comment: The analogy in this case would be closer to: 'granting access to my friends into my house will not grant them access to my father's safeguard that I cannot open myself'

Comment: @dribeas: Yes - your analogy is closer to the C++ behavior.

Answer (score 7):

A friend of `Derived` can access exactly what `Derived` itself can - that is, any member of `Derived`, and any public or protected member of any base class, or of any public or protected grand-parent class, but **not** any private members of base classes, or members of private grand-parent classes.

Answer (score 2):

Private members are not accessible in derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

The friend function has access to all members of *Derived*.  It doesn't have access to any members of *Base* that *Derived* can't access.  Derived can't access *Base::c* because *Base::c* is private.